# Unable to see AppIdentifier

Tags: ios, xcode4.2

I am unable to see the app identifier in xcode organizer!

[image: Screen Shot]

I am using XCode - 4.2. What causes this problem?

Comment: Did you check the info.plist file?

Comment: [projectname]-Info.plist file, and look at the Bundle identifier property.

Comment: Hmm... I am asking in case I am opening the provisioning profile for the first time!! We have to manually give the value in info.plist, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the provisioning profile to the project (double click on the project). After this, you should setup the App Identifier (you can see it even in the provisioning profile - open the project file, select from the "targets" the project, select the "Build Settings" tab, and find the Code Signing Identity. Open the list, and there you can see the installed provisioning profile, with the corresponding app identifiers for each other). So, this app identifier you should put in the:

1. [projname]-Info.plist file, to the bundle identifier property
2. project file -> targets -> select the project -> summary -> Identifier (warning: you cannot modify the Identifier if in the Info.plist file at the bundle identifier you have `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`. In this case you should change from the info.plist file).

Now, go back to the Build Settings, and you will be able now to select the corresponding provisioning profile. If it's necessary: select from the left list: project -> Project name -> build settings tab -> Code signing -> select the provisioning profile.

Now, in the organiser should be visible the app identifier.

Comment: No luck Molly!! :-) Still the same issue!!

Comment: Would you mind to verify then the app identifier in the build settings tab? Is the correct provisioning profile selected?